# System.OutOfMemoryException in 32-Bit Application

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli

As my Master's thesis I'm currently creating a software for different tasks in X-Ray-Physics. The software is written in Visual C++. Net using Visual Studio 2015 and it is only for 32-Bit systems.

Today I've noticed an error called `System.OutOfMemoryException in System.Drawing.dll`.
The error occurs when I'm importing a "large" file into my application.

The debugging tool of Visual Studio 2015 told me that the error occurs inside the function below. I've already created a comment at the line of the code where the error should be coming from, according to the debugging tool. Uncommenting the rest of the code below the comment will solve the `OutOfMemoryException`, but should not be my goal. It would make the software less user-friendly.

**Question: Can anyone find an error inside the function below (and post the solution), or has a good hint so solve my problem?**

If you need additional information, please tell me. I didn't want to go to much into detail if it's not necessary (>10.000 lines of code, lots of physics).

Original Code:

```
void ManageComposition::CheckFontSetting(TreeNode^ treenode, bool checklines)
{
    int result;
    if (treenode->Nodes->Count!=0)
    {
        if ((treenode->Tag->GetType()->Name=="Element" && checklines) || treenode->Tag->GetType()->Name=="Composition")
            {
            IEnumerator^ treenodeenum = treenode->Nodes->GetEnumerator();
            while (treenodeenum->MoveNext())
            {
                this->CheckFontSetting(safe_cast<TreeNode^>(treenodeenum->Current),checklines);
            }
        }
    }
    if (treenode->Tag->GetType()->Name=="Composition" && this->WithLines())
    {
        result=safe_cast<Composition^>(treenode->Tag)->CheckCalculationParamters(this->normalizeto100);
        switch (result)
        {
        case 0: 
            treenode->BackColor=Color::LightGreen;
            break;
        case 1: 
            if (this->mode=="calculate intensities")
                treenode->BackColor=Color::Red;
            else if (this->mode=="calculate concentrations")
                treenode->BackColor=Color::LightGreen;
            else if (this->mode=="compare relative intensities")
                treenode->BackColor=Color::Red;
            break;
        case 2: 
            if (this->mode=="calculate concentrations")
                treenode->BackColor=Color::Red;
            else if (this->mode=="calculate intensities")
                treenode->BackColor=Color::LightGreen;
            else if (this->mode=="compare relative intensities")
                treenode->BackColor=Color::Red;
            break;
        case 3:
            treenode->BackColor=Color::Red;
            break;
        }
    }
    // This is the point where the errors occur while handling large lists
// uncommenting the rest of this code will solve the error, but functionality will be lost

    else if (treenode->Tag->GetType()->Name=="Element")
    {
        if (safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetSymbol()!=treenode->Text)
        {
            if (safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetIntensity(treenode->Text)!=0.0)
            {
                treenode->NodeFont=gcnew System::Drawing::Font(treenode->TreeView->Font,FontStyle::Bold);
                treenode->Text=treenode->Text;
            }
            else if (safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetGroupIntensity(treenode->Text)!=0.0)
            {
                treenode->NodeFont=gcnew System::Drawing::Font(treenode->TreeView->Font,FontStyle::Bold);
                treenode->Text=treenode->Text;
            }
            else
            {
                treenode->NodeFont=gcnew System::Drawing::Font(treenode->TreeView->Font,FontStyle::Regular);
                treenode->Text=treenode->Text;
            } // Visual Studio debugging tool points on the condition below
            if (safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->IsGroupSelected(treenode->Text) || safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetTransition(treenode->Text)->IsSelected())
            {
                treenode->BackColor=Color::Aquamarine;
            }
            else
            {
                treenode->BackColor=this->treeview->BackColor;
            } 

        }
        else
        {
            bool red=false;
            if (this->mode=="calculate concentrations" || this->mode=="compare relative intensities")
            {
                if (safe_cast<Composition^>(safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->owner)->IsRootComposition())
                {
                    if (safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetIntensitySum()==0.0)
                    {
                        if (safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetConcentration()==0.0)
                        {
                            red=true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetIntensitySum()==0.0)
                    {
                        if (safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetConcentration()==0.0)
                        {
                            red=true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                array<String^>^ dummy=safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetRelevantLines();
                if (dummy->Length>1)
                {
                    int x;
                    String^ groupname=safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetTransition(dummy[0])->GetGroup();
                    for(x=1;x<dummy->Length;x++)
                    {
                        if (groupname!=safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetTransition(dummy[x])->GetGroup())
                            red=true; 
                    }
                }
            }
            if ((this->mode=="calculate intensities" || this->mode=="compare relative intensities")&& safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetConcentration()==0.0)
                red=true;
            if (red)
                treenode->BackColor=Color::Red;
            else
                treenode->BackColor=Color::LightGreen;
        } 
    } 
}
```

Updated function with @Hans Olsson's idea:

```
void ManageComposition::CheckFontSetting(TreeNode^ treenode, bool checklines)
{

Font^ BoldFont = gcnew System::Drawing::Font(treenode->TreeView->Font, FontStyle::Bold);
Font^ RegularFont = gcnew System::Drawing::Font(treenode->TreeView->Font, FontStyle::Regular);

    int result;
    if (treenode->Nodes->Count!=0)
    {
        if ((treenode->Tag->GetType()->Name=="Element" && checklines) || treenode->Tag->GetType()->Name=="Composition")
            {
            IEnumerator^ treenodeenum = treenode->Nodes->GetEnumerator();
            while (treenodeenum->MoveNext())
            {
                this->CheckFontSetting(safe_cast<TreeNode^>(treenodeenum->Current),checklines);
            }
        }
    }
    if (treenode->Tag->GetType()->Name=="Composition" && this->WithLines())
    {
        result=safe_cast<Composition^>(treenode->Tag)->CheckCalculationParamters(this->normalizeto100);
        switch (result)
        {
        case 0: 
            treenode->BackColor=Color::LightGreen;
            break;
        case 1: 
            if (this->mode=="calculate intensities")
                treenode->BackColor=Color::Red;
            else if (this->mode=="calculate concentrations")
                treenode->BackColor=Color::LightGreen;
            else if (this->mode=="compare relative intensities")
                treenode->BackColor=Color::Red;
            break;
        case 2: 
            if (this->mode=="calculate concentrations")
                treenode->BackColor=Color::Red;
            else if (this->mode=="calculate intensities")
                treenode->BackColor=Color::LightGreen;
            else if (this->mode=="compare relative intensities")
                treenode->BackColor=Color::Red;
            break;
        case 3:
            treenode->BackColor=Color::Red;
            break;
        }
    }
    // This is the point where the errors occur while handling large lists
    // uncommenting the rest of this code will solve the error, but functionality will be lost
    else if (treenode->Tag->GetType()->Name=="Element")
    {
        if (safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetSymbol()!=treenode->Text)
        {
            if (safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetIntensity(treenode->Text)!=0.0)
            {
                if (BoldFont) treenode->NodeFont = BoldFont;
                treenode->Text=treenode->Text;
            }
            else if (safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetGroupIntensity(treenode->Text)!=0.0)
            {
                if (BoldFont) treenode->NodeFont = BoldFont;
                treenode->Text=treenode->Text;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!RegularFont) treenode->NodeFont = RegularFont;
                treenode->Text=treenode->Text;
            }

            // Visual Studio debugging tool points to the condition below

            if (safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->IsGroupSelected(treenode->Text) || safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetTransition(treenode->Text)->IsSelected())
            {
                treenode->BackColor = Color::Aquamarine;
            }
            else
            {
                treenode->BackColor=this->treeview->BackColor;
            } 

        }
        else
        {
            bool red=false;
            if (this->mode=="calculate concentrations" || this->mode=="compare relative intensities")
            {
                if (safe_cast<Composition^>(safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->owner)->IsRootComposition())
                {
                    if (safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetIntensitySum()==0.0)
                    {
                        if (safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetConcentration()==0.0)
                        {
                            red=true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetIntensitySum()==0.0)
                    {
                        if (safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetConcentration()==0.0)
                        {
                            red=true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                array<String^>^ dummy=safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetRelevantLines();
                if (dummy->Length>1)
                {
                    int x;
                    String^ groupname=safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetTransition(dummy[0])->GetGroup();
                    for(x=1;x<dummy->Length;x++)
                    {
                        if (groupname!=safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetTransition(dummy[x])->GetGroup())
                            red=true; 
                    }
                }
            }
            if ((this->mode=="calculate intensities" || this->mode=="compare relative intensities")&& safe_cast<Element^>(treenode->Tag)->GetConcentration()==0.0)
                red=true;
            if (red)
                treenode->BackColor=Color::Red;
            else
                treenode->BackColor=Color::LightGreen;
        } 
    } 
}
```

**NOTE:** The application uses less than 50 MB of Ram while loading the file containing the data.

Comment: How many nodes with NodeFont changed are there? I suspect that you allocate too many Font instances, and that every instance is quite heavy.

Comment: I guess about 45. Give me 10 minutes and I'll check it out.

Comment: This is not related to your problem, but there are some things you need to fix there: 1. use enums instead of strings (eg for `this->mode`), 2. use a `for each` loop instead of enumerators directly, 3. Use `dynamic_cast` instead of reflection, or better yet, use polymorphism.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski thank's - I'll take care of it after solving the actual problem :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Dmitry-T that you likely have to many font-changes; just create bold-face etc once and then reuse that:
Instead of code such as:

```
 treenode->NodeFont=gcnew System::Drawing::Font(treenode->TreeView->Font,FontStyle::Bold);
```

declare BoldFont at the start of function and do something like:

```
 if (!BoldFont) BoldFont=gcnew System::Drawing::Font(treenode->TreeView->Font,FontStyle::Bold);
 treenode->NodeFont=BoldFont;
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer! I'll try it out and will report to you :-)

Comment: Sorry for the wrong comment bevore. Your solution works perfectly! Thanks a lot! This if-conditions are the hint.